# Node.js RESTful API on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cloud-shell

I'm trying to take my first steps in node.js and I've been following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-nodejs-api-app
When I'm typing `npm install -g yo` to the cloud shell in azure I get this error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-83-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/shiran_dror/app-service-api-node-contact-list/npm-debug.log
```

How do I use the shell as root/Administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to install Swaggerize on your local machine, not in the Cloud Shell.

> Install Swaggerize **on your local machine**. Swaggerize is a tool that generates Node.js code for your REST API from a Swagger definition.

When done developing locally, push to App Service with git (section "Deploy the API with Git" from the docs).

Answer (score 1):

In Cloud Shell today you are set as a [regular user without sudo permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/limitations#user-permissions). As a result you cannot run sudo cmds from Cloud Shell currently. In the tutorial you are following, Cloud Shell helps for the [sections that require `az` commands to create the Azure app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-nodejs-api-app#createapiapp) since the Azure CLI 2.0 is maintained and updated for you there.

The [section where you are npm installing Swaggerize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-nodejs-api-app#prepare-your-environment) is meant to be on your local machine, the instructions include this detail.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your user doesn't have the permission to install in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`. Try removing the `-g` option to install locally.

Use `sudo` in front of `npm install` command to switch to root user for this command (if you're allowed to do that).